# No route matches [POST] "/maps/1/rows/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to add a row to a map but am getting a route error:

> No route matches [POST] "/maps/1/rows/new"

If I do a rake routes I see that there is a route for this in there so I am a bit confused as to why.

`new_map_row GET    /maps/:map_id/rows/new(.:format)      rows#new`

This is the form that I am using to create this row.

```
<%= form_for @row, method: 'post', url: new_map_row_path do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :timeframe %>
    <%= form.text_field :timeframe %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Rows Controller

```
def create
    @row = @map.rows.create(params[:row].permit(:timestamp))
    @row.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @row.save
        format.html { redirect_to @row.map, notice: 'Row was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

### Rows Model

```
class Row < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :map
end
```

Comment: I now realize that this is because the route states this as a get and the form is posting. How can this be fixed?

Comment: `post 'maps/:map_id/rows' => 'maps#create'`? in routes.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't post to the `new` action itself, that's what renders the form. The destination for the `create` phase, the follow-up to `new`, is actually the collection path with method POST:

```
<%= form_for @row, method: :post, url: map_rows_path do |form| %>
```

That's where the `create` action kicks in.